# Binding HTML elements to XML fields

Tags: html, xml, internet-explorer

I am trying "Tutorial 9 - Using XML as a Data Source" of the book "New Perspectives on XML, 2nd Edition by Patrick Carey". I found the materials from [this link](http://bcs.solano.edu/datfiles/CIS%2072/Tutorial.02X/Tutorial/) from a simple web search.

This is part of .htm file.

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Freezing Point Refrigerators</title>
   <link href="styles1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <xml id="pageInfo" src="fpinfo.xml"></xml>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="pageTitle" datasrc="#pageInfo" datafld="title"></div>
   <div id="pageSubtitle" datasrc="#pageInfo" datafld="subtitle"></div>
   <div id="pageText" datasrc="#pageInfo" datafld="purpose"></div>
   <div id="pageAuthor">For more information, contact: 
        <a datasrc="#pageInfo" datafld="authorEmail">
          <span datasrc="#pageInfo" datafld="author"></span>
        </a>.
   </div>
```

Following is the content of the "fpinfo.xml" file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<information>
   <title>Freezing Point Refrigerators</title>
   <subtitle>Staff Information Page</subtitle>
   <purpose>
      This page contains information on the staff of Freezing Point 
      Refrigerators. Staff members are divided into four groups: Accounting, 
      Sales, Manufacturing, and Advertising. Each employee's name, department, 
      position, phone number, years employed, and job status (full- or 
      part-time) is reported.
   </purpose>
   <author>Catherine Davis</author>
   <authorEmail>mailto:cdavis@freezingpoint.com</authorEmail>
</information>
```

This is the expected output:

[image]

But this is what I get in IE browser:
[image]

Why the title and other xml fields are not correctly displayed? Following is the developer tools view.
[image]

Even the xml line `<xml id="pageInfo" src="fpinfo.xml"></xml>` is in the .htm header field, it can be seen under body tag of the developer view. What am I doing wrong here. Thank you.

Comment: that book was published way back 2006 and I suppose the browser version used back then when the book was written is IE6 (or probably IE5). DSO theoretically can still work at this time and age considering that ActiveX-based technologies were just recently ditched off, but what are you trying to achieve here by studying an old data binding technology?

Comment: @RomanCanlas, really thank you very much for pointing that out. I am little new to this field of linking HTML to XML. Would you have any good book suggestion for this, or where should I raise that question (as it won't be a good question in SO). Thank you.

Comment: There are more modern ways of binding your web app to XML data but it involves more than studying HTML and XML. Anyone in the forum can point you a web technology stack and either one will suit. I may be bias as I'm coming from a Microsoft-based technology stack, but I suggest you to study ASP.NET and it's XML data binding mechanisms http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_xml.asp - that is if you are trying to learn to develop a data-driven app. If your focus is more on XML, its structure and how it can be utilized as a data store, I suggest you start from there http://www.w3schools.com/xml/

Answer (score 0):

It seems [these examples](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes_get.asp) on W3Schools are working.

And also [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_xmlhttprequest_xml) is interesting, with a triggering button though.

(But it became more complicated, I don't even get why. That old code above in the question was beautiful, clear, one-lined. Personal Growl OFF.)